# How to change the graph name in Apache-AGE?

Tags: apache-age

I have a **Graph** with the name `people` created inside my **apache** database.
But now I want to update it to `population`

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

To rename the function from `people` to `population`, you can use the `ALTER FUNCTION` statement:

```
ALTER FUNCTION people() RENAME TO population;
```

This statement renames the function `people` to `population`.

After executing this statement, you should be able to call the function using its new name `population()`. Note that any other database objects that reference the old function name would need to be updated accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

In order to change the graph name from 'people' to 'population' use alter_graph() as follows:

```
SELECT alter_graph('people', 'RENAME', 'population');
```

You can also crosscheck this by issuing the following command:

```
SELECT * FROM ag_graph;
```

The *name* and *namespace* columns should have 'population' in it

Answer (score 0):

You can update the graph name from 'People' to 'Population' using the following query:

```
ALTER GRAPH people RENAME TO population;
```

You can also use this query:

```
RENAME GRAPH people TO population;
```